# Is there a way to take the citations from my bibtex file and move them into my tex file without having to change the formatting?

Tags: bibliographies

I have a large number of citations in the format

```
Dadrichetal2015,
Author = {Dadrich, M. and Nicolay, N.H. and Flechsig, P. and  Bickelhaupt, S. and 
Hoeltgen, L. and Roeder, F. and Hauser, K. and Tietz, A. and Jenne, J. and Lopez, R. 
and Roehrich, M. and Wirkner, U. and Lahn, M. and Huber, P.E.},
Title = {Combined inhibition of TGF$\beta$ and PDGF signaling attenuates radiation- 
induced pulmonary fibrosis.},
Journal = {Oncoimmunology},
Volume = {5},
Year = {2015},
note = {https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=dadrich+M\%2C+Oncoimmunology}}
```

In a `.bib` file. I am having enormous trouble making the `.bib` file work, and have decide to just do it manually. Is there a way for me to move the citations from the `.bib` to the `.tex`, have them display properly without having to basically rewrite all my citations?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a bit more information regarding the "I am having enormous trouble making the .bib file work" claim. E.g., is it the fact that the bib entry is lacking a type designation? Is it the fact that your document may be lacking `\bibliographystyle`  and `\bibliography` statements? Please tell us more as to which problems you're looking to solve?

Comment: I have given up on making this bibliography work as a seperate `.bib` document, It was just a different version of an earlier `.bib` that did work. I had the calling statements you mentioned, I checked all the labels and `\cite` for typos, it just kept giving me warnings about undefined labes for every citation. The issue now is just trying to save some time and work by taking the format from the .bib and using it for my references within the .tex without having to completly redo them.

Comment: Whatever the problems you’re having with the .bib file are, why do you expect they’ll be fixed by moving the .bib entries into the .tex file? A simpler approach to troubleshooting would be make a new .bib file, and tell the document to use that, copy the entires a few at a time from the old to the new, recompiling the file in betwee to see when the mysterious errors reappear (ie any bibtex errors/warnings apart from the expected “undefined citation” for entries you haven et yet moved to the new file).

Answer (score 3):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

You asked,

> Is there a way to take the [bibliographic entries] from my bibtex file and move them into my tex file without having to change the formatting?

The short answer is, "No".

The long answer is, "Unless you want to do the equivalent of reinventing the wheel, the answer is No."

You haven't stated what exactly "doesn't work" about the bib entry. The following setup, though, works fine. The main creative act you'll have to perform is pick a suitable bibliography style; `abbrvnat` is just one of many, many possible choices.

Note that I

- added some pairs of curly braces in the `author` field to prevent BibTeX from 
  lowercasing some words,
- replaced `\beta` with `\upbeta`,
- changed the `note` field to `url`, and
- replaced the URL string with information provided by the journal directly.

The code also loads the `xurl` and `hyperref` packages. To compile this document, be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on it.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Dadrichetal2015,
Author = {Monika Dadrich and Nils H. Nicolay and 
          Paul Flechsig and Sebastian Bickelhaupt and 
          Line Hoeltgen and Falk Roeder and Kai Hauser 
          and Alexandra Tietz and Jürgen Jenne and 
          Ramon Lopez and Manuel Roehrich and 
          Ute Wirkner and Michael Lahn and 
          Peter E. Huber},
Title  = {Combined inhibition of {TGF$\upbeta$} 
          and {PDGF} signaling attenuates 
          radiation-induced pulmonary fibrosis},
Journal= {Oncoimmunology},
Volume = 5,
Number = 5,
Pages  = {e1123366},
Year   = 2015,
url    = {https://doi.org/10.1080/2162402X.2015.1123366},
doi    = {10.1080/2162402X.2015.1123366},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % citation management package
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} % choose a suitable bib style
\hyphenation{onco-immu-no-logy}
\usepackage{upgreek}  % for "\upbeta" macro
\usepackage{xurl}  % allow line breaks anywhere in a URL string
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{Dadrichetal2015}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```